# Java - getting runtime information

Tags: java

Hy, I am need to know how to get a history of the runtime. I need to get information about every thread, and every class it has been trough, and every method, and every object that has been created. Something like a debugger. just that I need all that information in a file. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Uhm, maybe it is doable but I do hope you have _very_ fast storage.

Comment: @fge is he asking about log4j ??

Comment: @Baadshah I don't believe so... log4j doesn't track `new` calls. But yeah, it sounds like an XY problem

Comment: Your description reminds me about this tool : http://chrononsystems.com/ .

Comment: You can use AOP to add some behavior before and after each method call. Then, trace the result.

Comment: try the %t operator in patternLayout of log4j, that will give info about the thread and %x for NDC of the thread

Comment: OK, so: what do you want to do exactly? I really can't imagine you want to collect each and every allocation/thread creation of a JVM. Too much information kills information.

Comment: At first sight your explanation looks a bit like that of a [profiler](http://www.yourkit.com/).  But at a high level of detail these have a very significant impact on performance, and generate tons of output which makes them only suitable for short runs.  I agree with others, what exacty do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You  may need to explore about the [JVM TI APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/).

> The JVM tool interface (JVM TI) is a native programming interface for
>   use by tools. It provides both a way to inspect the state and to
>   control the execution of applications running in the Java virtual
>   machine (JVM). JVM TI supports the full breadth of tools that need
>   access to JVM state, including but not limited to: profiling,
>   debugging, monitoring, thread analysis, and coverage analysis tools.
>
> Note: JVM TI was introduced at JDK 5.0. JVM TI replaces the Java
>   Virtual Machine Profiler Interface (JVMPI) and the Java Virtual
>   Machine Debug Interface (JVMDI) which, as of JDK 6, are no longer
>   provided.

Debuggers such as [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) uses this interface to get the insight about the JVM and different stats.

Comment: +1,Don't know weather its useful to OP or not . I never heard about it..  :)

Comment: @Baadshah This is the best thing about SO. You got to know about so many things. Loving this benefit :-)

Comment: @Baadshah "whether", not "weather" :p*

Comment: @fge Lol...can't edit comment now..please keep your comment ,as a correction for it :P